# Bare Metal/Native Hypervisors?

Tags: virtualization

there are two types of hypervisors.  As in http://www.tricerat.com/topics/hypervisor. I would like to know some examples for Bare Metal/Native Hypervisors ?

examples for Embedded/Host Hypervisors = vmware , xen , virtual pc

am i correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think [Hyper-V](http://www.microsoft.com/hyper-v-server/en/us/default.aspx) is an example of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Bare metal virtualization can be done using RedHat Vitalization Hypervisor 3.2 or 3.3 latest and open source is oVirt.

They do not require OS to run hypevisor on host and manager usually runs on another machine or guest to save host resources where hypervisor is installed.

Yes Xen and Vmware ESXi are also hypervisors used for bare metal virtualization.